# Подсчет количества уникальных значений c несколькими условиями

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Есть таблица `products` с полями `id_product`, `title`, `visibility`, `id_parent`. Поле с неуникальным значением - `id_parent`. Задача - получить количество уникальных значений `id_parent`, удовлетворяющих условиям. Конструкция ниже не работает, выдаётся явно большее количество записей, чем количество уникальных и удовлетворяющих условию. Прошу совета в составлении правильного запроса.

```
 $query = "SELECT count(`id_product`) FROM `products` 
           WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$title."%' 
           AND `visibility` = '' 
           group by `id_parent`
          ";
```

Comment: `select count(distinct id_parent) ...` и никакого group by, если вам нужно одно значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct id_parent)
  FROM `products` 
 WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$title."%' 
   AND `visibility` = ''
```

Comment: Mike, насколько запрос с distinct ресурсоемкий? На форумах пишут, что на очень большой таблице может повесить хостинг.

Comment: @118_64 Практически аналогичен group by. Выполняется сортировка по этому полю и по отсортированному считается. Ваш like начинающийся  `%` то же ресурсоемкий, гарантированно перебирается вся таблица, индексы использоваться не могут